# How can I conigure my project to use Hibernate to automatically generate a mapped entity class that represent a DB table?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, code-generation, entities

I have not big experience with **Hibernate** and **JPA** and I have the following task to achieve.

So I have some tables on the database, for example this table one named **TWS1017_CITTADINA**:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COD_CIT                                   NOT NULL CHAR(4)                     
 DES_COD_CIT                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60)                
 DAT_ORA_ULT_MOV                           NOT NULL DATE                        
 COD_PGM_ULT_MOV                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)                
 COD_UTE_ULT_MOV                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)                
 COD_COM_EST                                        CHAR(4)                     
 COD_STA_EST_IST                                    CHAR(4)                     
 COD_SOG_PRO                                        CHAR(4)                     
 COD_CON                                            CHAR(2)                     
 COD_SIG                                            VARCHAR2(5)                 
 DES_SOG                                            VARCHAR2(60)                
 DAT_IST                                            DATE                        
 DAT_SOP                                            DATE                        
 DAT_VAR                                            DATE                        
 COD_STA_EST_ISO                                    VARCHAR2(2)
```

Ok, now on a **Spring MVC** application I have to use **JPA** (using **Hibernate** as implementation) to automatically generate a mapped entity starting from this table.

I am using **Eclipse** as IDE and I have found this tutorial:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm

From what I have understand I have to configure the project **facets** (what exactly is a facet?).

The problem is that in this tutorial seems use **Eclipse Link** as JPA implementation and not Hibernate.

So I think that to generate my mapped entity starting from the previous database table I first have to include **Hibernate** in my project (into the **pom.xml** file) and then add some jar related to Hibernate instead use Eclipse Link. Or something like this.

But I really have no idea about how to do it. Can someone help me to do this first step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate Tools - I've used this to automatically generate entities from tables.

Perhaps the following tutorial will be more useful.

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#refeng_codegen